# Convergence in distribution and sequence converging to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

If $X_{n}\to 0$ in distribution . Then I am required to Find a sequence $x_{n}\to 0$. Such that
$\mathbb{P}(|X_{n}|\geq x_{n})\to 0$.

My initial idea is using Skorohod's Representation theorem to find $Y_{n}$ which converges to $0$ almost surely Hence in probability also.

Then there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|Y_{n}|\geq \frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n},$ $\forall n\geq m$. Then $\mathbb{P}(|X_{n}|\geq \frac{1}{n})=\mathbb{P}(|Y_{n}|\geq \frac{1}{n})$ . Then would this suffice?.
I am having doubt regarding the previous step.

What is the correct way of approaching this?. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(|Y_{n}|\geq \frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}, \forall n\geq m$ does not look quite right.

Comment: @Henry Then how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any sequence $\epsilon_n\searrow 0$. Since $X_n\xrightarrow{d}0$, for each $k\ge 1$, there exists $n_k\ge 1$ s.t. $\mathsf{P}(|X_n|\ge \epsilon_k)<\epsilon_k$ for all $n\ge n_k$. Then, you can construct $x_n$ recursively, i.e., set $x_1=\cdots=x_{n_1-1}=1$, $x_{n_1}=\cdots,x_{n_2-1}=\epsilon_1$, and so on.

Comment: Ah yes. That's the trick I was totally missing. I wanted to use subsequence but could not create it. Thanks

Comment: That's correct. However, you don't need to use the a.s. representation. It suffices to invoke the definition of convergence in distribution.